# Draw mesh/surf plot without certain point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mesh, surf

I would like to draw a mesh plot. As the function goes, it always plots all the entries inside the input matrix. However, now I want a certain entry not to draw out, for example:

```
x = 1:3
y = 1:3
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = [2,2,2;4,4,4;5,5,0];
```

where "0" is the entry I would not like to draw. 
After using mesh(X,Y,Z) or surf(X,Y,Z), it still shows that point with height = 0
[image]

Is there any way to hide that point? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `0`with `inf`:

```
x = 1:3
y = 1:3
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = [2,2,2;4,4,4;5,5,inf];
```

`inf` is typically ignored by drawing commands.